# How to go about solving series of form: $\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given some series
\begin{equation*}
(s_n)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}a_n
\end{equation*}
How do I go about solving this? I can't apply any test since '$n=-1$' (as far as I am aware).

I was thinking something like
\begin{equation*}
a_{-1}+a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n
\end{equation*}
and then apply some sort of test. Not sure how the '$a_{-1}+a_0$' would affect the result though.

I can provide an example series if needed.

Comment: The added terms wouldn't affect the convergence, it would just add an additional finite value to the sum.

Comment: Constants in the beginning don’t affect standard convergence.  There are some wacky ways of evaluating divergent series where it does matter, but that probably isn’t what you’re doing.

Comment: @Eric "There are some wacky ways of evaluating divergent series where it does matter" you do have my interest now ;)

Comment: So I could for example use root test on $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ and if it were to converge then so would $(s_n)$?

Comment: Yes because the difference is just $a_{-1}+a_0,$ which is finite.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help.

Comment: For the OP’s question - yes you could apply the root test and it would give the correct result. 

For divergent series where applying advanced methods like Cutoff regulation to get out a sum (ex: $1+2+3...=-1/12$), adding a beginning term could modify the sum. See “Failure of stable linear summation methods” here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_⋯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the beginning by $s_n$ you meant $s$ ie \begin{equation*}
s=\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}a_n.
\end{equation*}

As long as $a_{-1}$ is some finite number, there is no issue with applying any of the techniques you know by far. By the way, what you said is correct, but you don't need to think that way. Whenever we're dealing with sequences "eventual behavior" is the key thing we consider. We don't bother much with the finitely many terms that appear at the beginning of the sequence. For example, if $$ x_n = \frac{1}{n}$$ and

$ y_n = 10^{1000}$  if $n \leq 1000,$ and  $y_n = \frac{1}{n}$ if $ n> 1000,$ then both $x_n$ and $y_n$ converge to $0.$

Comment: Cool. So if I were to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\rightarrow0$ should I just state:
Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, so does $a_{-1}+a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$?

Comment: You're right but you need to be a little bit careful. The argument for convergence is perfectly okay, but the limit may be different.  I mean to compute the infinite sum, you just need to add the first two terms with  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n.$ Does this make sense?

Comment: Yup. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.